# How junit this observable async method

Tags: java, java-8, reactive-programming, observable, lettuce

I have repo that tests an async execution using java8 and reactive:

interface of zadd:

```
Observable<Long> zadd(K key, double score, V member);



 public class TargetClass()
{
..
     public void executeMethod(List<String> input) {
            input.forEach(item -> redisConnection.reactive().zadd(...).subscribe(
                    result -> log.info("Success")
                    error -> log.error("Failed...")
            ));
        }
..
}
```

my junit testing code:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
  TargetClass targetClass=new TargetClass();
    targetClass.executeMethod(Arrays.asList("input1", "input2", "input3"));

    //as you can see I must put here Thread.sleep in order to let my execution to finish before continue since we have dependency on it

    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //continue with testing..
```

how can I modify my code parts rights. It doesn't feel right to add `Thread.sleep` to let the async method code to take place

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: Take a look at [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: @the8472 i know future. can you add a relevant  example?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would overload the method `executeMethod` by adding 2 new parameters, one parameter will be the function to execute on `success` and the other one on `failure`. I would make the new method `protected` instead of `public` and I would test this new method in my unit test instead of the other one. Your `public` method can call the new one with this `executeMethod(input, result -> log.info("Success"), error -> log.error("Failed..."))`. In my unit test I can then provide a way to get the result with something like this:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
    TargetClass targetClass = new TargetClass();
    AtomicBoolean success = new AtomicBoolean();
    synchronized (success) {
        targetClass.executeMethod(
            list, 
            result -> {
                synchronized (success) {
                    success.set(true);
                    success.notify();
                } 
            }, 
            error -> {
                synchronized (success) {
                    success.set(false);
                    success.notify();
                } 
            }
        );
        success.wait();
    }
    // The rest of your unit test here
}
```

Comment: where would you override it? on my target class ? thats abit of boilerplate code for that class isnt it? i am going to duplicate all my methods on my target-class with this attitude

Comment: In your implementation class. BTW I propose to **overload** not to override, it's 2 different concepts.

Comment: i know the meaning of overloading. on that case you still adding 'boilerplate' code(overloading every method) for unit-testing purposes which feeling abit not right

Comment: I don't think this way, for me If you can't unit test your own class, it is more a design issue, maybe you should re-review your design. Anyway I don't understand what you don't like in this approach but I believe it will still be better than a single sleep moreover how do you get the result with your approach?

Comment: you right mybe something is wrong with my design. I very welcome a design improvement from your side aswell. in my method I dont get result. the thing is that my unit-testing adding this method as a 'preset' for other code to be executed. I can move on to the other code only after that one is finished.

Comment: Even if it is for a preset, you need a callback to be able to know when your environment is ready, what I proposed is a way to get your callback. BTW if it is a preset, you may consider to move this part of the code into a method annotated with @Before

Comment: You right. I moved it. but still as you said I need somehow to get a callback that the env is ready.